'If I were mayor, I'd make the public transport free.' What is the reported speech of this sentence beginning with 'she said'?
I am confused about the answer to this question in the Cambridge English Objective Proficiency Student Book Second Edition. The answer given is

She said that if she had been mayor, she would have made public transport free.

Why do the tenses change or "backshift" given the sentence is in second conditional? Shouldn't the tense "were and would" remain the same in the reported speech?

I think the backshifting is optional. I don't see anything wrong with She said that if she was mayor, she would make public transport free. To me, it's just a stylistic choice, but the (Past) Perfect forms definitely sound more "formal". Unless it was important to convey that the entire hypothetical scenario itself is firmly fixed in the past. If the possibility of her being mayor and making public transport free could only have arisen in the past (either she can no longer be mayor, or that policy option is no longer feasible), arguably you "need" to backshift.

@FumbleFingers what about She said that if she were mayor, she would make public transport free?

As FF says, the two renderings are synonymous. BUT I'd take the default reading here as an incorrect representation. I'd want 'She said that if she were[/was] mayor, she would make public transport free.' This is in accordance with the Gricean maxim of manner (specifically, be as clear as possible, especially avoiding ambiguity). The backshifted version has two meanings, and as I say the default reading is not the intended one.

She said that if she were mayor... is the explicitly subjunctive version of ...if she was mayor..., where the explicitly subjunctive version of the actual cited example She said that if she had been mayor... is ...if she were to have been mayor... As a general principle, native speakers increasingly avoid subjunctive forms, especially in conversational contexts.

@FumbleFingers I personally say: If I were x, all the time.

@Lambie: I'm just trying to make it easier for learners. As this usage chart shows, BrE uptake of Simple Past If I was you has been faster than AmE, but it's all heading in the same direction. If you don't need to pass exams, you can get by without subjunctive verbs in most contexts already, and it'll only become more so in future.

@FumbleFingers Well, I don't believe in "making it easier for learners" especially ones who are very advanced.

This question is similar to: If he had known she had too many commitments, he would have done something about it. (Backshifting within the scope of a modally remote preterite). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What was the task precisely? And what topic did the chapter of the book deal with? If this is from a workbook exercise, it's possible that the student is asked to use the past perfect because the chapter is about reported speech. Proficiency level is very advanced, equivalent to C2, on a par with native speakers, so things get trickier and more nuanced. Making it simpler, at this level, isn't going to help the student

She said, "If I were/ was the mayor, I would make public transport free." She said that if she had been mayor, she would have made public transport free. The backshifting has been applied. Second Conditional doesn't mean totally impossible (like the Third Conditional). Maybe these words were spoken by a candidate for the post and there is a chance she would win.

I don't think there's a shift. This is presumably referencing a specific point in time or a time period when the current mayor made the decision about what the cost of public transportation would be.

She said that if she had been mayor    (when the decision was made)
she would have made public transport free.

If it was:

She said that if she were mayor, she would have made public transport free.

That's acceptable, but the first sentence better emphasizes the specific period of time being referenced (when the decision was made). The second sentence could reference a longer, less-specific time when she might have been the mayor.

OP's query about whether tenses should change in a Second Conditional sentence:

"If I were mayor, I'd make the public transport free.".
What is the reported speech of this sentence beginning with 'she said'?

The answer provided in the Cambridge English Objective Proficiency Student Book suggests changing the tense.
However, the general rule for a Second Conditional sentence is that if the condition is still relevant, we do not backshift.

SECOND CONDITIONAL IN REPORTED SPEECH.
The above tense and modal shifting rules apply to the second conditional too. If the condition is still relevant, no changes occur.
However, if it’s outdated, the past simple becomes the past perfect, and would becomes would + have + past participle.
Sofia: If I had more money, I would buy a new car..

Sofia said that if she had more money, she would buy a new car. (Sofia still doesn’t have money, and  consequently, she can’t buy a new car.).
Sofia said that if she had had more money, she would have bought a new car. (The speaker remembers Sofia’s words and wishes from the past. Maybe Sofia doesn’t have any money issues now.)


Let’s apply this to the original sentence, assuming it was spoken as part of an election promise.
There are three possible situations when reporting it:
1. Elections Are Ongoing (Still Relevant).
If the election is still ongoing when the statement is reported, the condition remains hypothetical and relevant. No backshifting occurs:

She said that if she were mayor, she would make public transport free.

2. She Lost the Election (Past Unreal Condition).
If she lost the election, the condition refers to a past unreal situation.
In this case, the reported speech uses the third conditional to reflect the hypothetical past:

She said that if she had been mayor, she would have made public transport free.

3. She Won the Election (Real Condition).
If she was elected mayor, the condition is no longer hypothetical. The reported speech should reflect the real situation, removing the "if" clause to match the reality:

She said that as mayor, she would make public transport free..
OR.
She said that if she is elected mayor, she will make public transport free. (If reporting her promise before the election results were announced.)

The Cambridge example assumes the second scenario (she lost the election) and therefore backshifts to the third conditional.
However, it doesn’t address the other alternatives, such as the ongoing relevance of the condition (Scenario 1) or the situation where she is actually elected (Scenario 3).
